# Stored Procedure only gives a limited amount of results

Tags: mysql

My StoredProcedure only gives me a maximum amount of rows in the result equal to the amount of entries the table has.

So `call SP_Dashboard_getTransactionsPerDay("2018-03-19", "2018-04-25")` will give me:

```
date      | total
-----------------
2018-03-19| 0
2018-03-19| 0
```

if 2 entries are in the `event` table and not the full 38 requested days. The same call gives me 6 rows if there are 6 entries in `event` and 38 if there are at least 38 or more entries in `event`.

Is there any way to get a result for all requested days even if there are no entries in the `event` tabel?

My SP looks as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Dashboard_getTransactionsPerDay`(STARTDATE DATE,ENDDATE DATE)
BEGIN


set @i := -1;

SELECT
  DATE(ADDDATE(STARTDATE, INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS date,
  IFNULL(
      (
        SELECT
          COUNT(*) FROM event AS m2
        WHERE
          DATE(m2.created_at) = DATE(ADDDATE(STARTDATE, INTERVAL @i DAY))
          AND `m2`.`status` = 'ok'
      ),
      0) AS total
FROM
  event AS m1;
HAVING
  @i < DATEDIFF(ENDDATE, STARTDATE);
END
```

the table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` enum('new','ok','error') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: Do you have a calender/dates table in your db?

Comment: No I don´t have such a table currently but if it would fix it there is no reason not to add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a calender/dates table fixed the issue for me by adding the follwoing to my database:

a new table:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dates`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dates`;

CREATE TABLE `dates` (
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

a stored procedure to fill the new table automatically:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- StoredProcedure `SP_filldates`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_filldates;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_filldates(STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE)
  BEGIN
    WHILE STARTDATE <= ENDDATE DO
      INSERT INTO dates (date) VALUES (STARTDATE);
      SET STARTDATE = date_add(STARTDATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL SP_filldates('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31');
```

and the modification of my initially posted stored procedure:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- StoredProcedure `SP_Dashboard_getTransactionsPerDay`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS SP_Dashboard_getTransactionsPerDay;

DELIMITER $$


CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Dashboard_getTransactionsPerDay(
  STARTDATE DATE,
  ENDDATE   DATE
)
  BEGIN

    SET @i := -1;

    SELECT
      DATE(ADDDATE(STARTDATE, INTERVAL @i := @i + 1 DAY)) AS date,
      IFNULL(
          (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM event AS m2
            WHERE
              DATE(m2.created_at) = DATE(ADDDATE(STARTDATE, INTERVAL @i DAY))
              AND `m2`.`status` = 'ok'
          ),
          0
      ) AS total
    FROM
      dates AS m1
    HAVING
      @i < DATEDIFF(ENDDATE, STARTDATE);

  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This fix will work for all requests with a maximum of 365 rows cause the dates table only contains 365 entries in this case. If one needs more results the dates table must contain more dates.